# How to return different variables in NSDictionary for each button?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm coding a calculator for iPhone, and have a question.
I want to add three variable buttons, "a", "b", and "x". And this calculator has three test buttons, "T1", "T2", and "T3". Variables, a, b, and x have their own values for each test button.

> **For example:**
>
> - a = 1
> - b = 2
> - x = 3
>
> **T1**
>
> - a = 4
> - b = 5
> - x = 6
>
> **T2**
>
> - a = 7
> - b = 8
>
> **T3**
>
> - x = 9

If user doesn't touch any test button, default values are all zero. User touches any test button, values would be applied. My code is below.

```
    - (NSDictionary *)testVariableValue:(NSString *)test
    {
        NSArray *key = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"x", nil];
        NSMutableArray *object = nil;

        if([test isEqualToString:@"T1"] || [test isEqualToString:@"T2"] || [test isEqualToString:@"T3"])
        {
            if([test isEqualToString:@"T1"])
                object = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
            else if([test isEqualToString:@"T2"])
                object = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"5", @"6", nil];
            else if([test isEqualToString:@"T3"])
                object = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"7", @"8", @"9", nil];
            else
                object = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"0", @"0", nil];

            _dictionaryVariables = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:object forKeys:key];
            [_programStack removeLastObject];
        }
        return _dictionaryVariables;
    }
```

But it didn't work properly. When I touched any test button, it was ok. But after I touched a, b, or x button without test buttons and set all zero values, test buttons didn't work. I have no idea how to set values for each test button after set up all zero for variables.

Forgive my english. Thank you so much for your time to read this!

Comment: "But after I touched a, b, or x button without test buttons"--What code is called from pressing these buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

In your header (.h) file, put this in:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSInteger aValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSInteger bValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSInteger xValue;

//Define new methods
-(IBAction)changeValuesT1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)changeValuesT2:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)changeValuesT3:(id)sender;
```

In the implementation (.m) file, put this in:

```
//changeValues method body
-(IBAction)changeValuesT1:(id)sender{

    self.aValue = 1;
    self.bValue = 2;
    self.xValue = 3;

}
-(IBAction)changeValuesT2:(id)sender{

    self.aValue = 4;
    self.bValue = 5;
    self.xValue = 6;

}
-(IBAction)changeValuesT3:(id)sender{

    self.aValue = 7;
    self.bValue = 8;
    self.xValue = 9;

}

//viewDidLoad

self.aValue = 0;
self.bValue = 0;
self.xValue = 0;
```

Hope this helps!